# play, java8 - re-use test fake application in tests?

Tags: testing, playframework

is there anyway to stop the actor system from shutting down and starting up between tests?
I keep getting akka exceptions complaining about the actor system being down.
I can mock/stub to get rid of the reliance on the fake app but it needs a bit of work - hoping to be able to just start one static test application up and run different things in the app.

Eg I have a (crappy) test like this - can I somehow re-use the running app between tests? it still seems to shut down somewhere along the line.

```
running(Fixtures.testSvr, HTMLUNIT, browser -> new JavaTestKit(system) {{
            F.Promise<TestResponseObject> resultPromise = client.makeRequest("request", "parameterObject", system.dispatcher());

            boolean gotUnmarshallingException = false;
            try {
                Await.result(resultPromise.wrapped(), TotesTestFixtures.timeout.duration());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if ((e instanceof exceptions.UnmarshallingException)) {
                    gotUnmarshallingException = true;
                }
            }

            if(gotUnmarshallingException == false) fail();
        }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to get rid of the `running` method (it stops the testserver at the end) and initialize a testserver by yourself, but I don't know if Akka will be available to you:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void start() {
    testServer = testServer(PORT, fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase()));
    testServer.start();
    // Maybe you dont ned this...
    try {
        testbrowser = new TestBrowser(HTMLUNIT, "http://localhost:" + PORT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }     
}

@Test
public void testOne() {
    new JavaTestKit() {
     // (...)
    }   
}

@AfterClass
public static void stop() {        
    testServer.stop();
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Forgot I had opened this question.I did start(TestServer). Same diff :)